# org beamer export vs < symbol

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

I'm using org mode beamer export.

I have an itemized list

I want an item to start with the text "<7ms"

It seems to be almost impossible to quote the "<" character so that the org parser doesn't think it's an overlay, and pass it into LaTeX, which then chokes on it.

I believe writing "\item{} <7ms" would work, but I can't seem to find any way to write this in org so that I get that result in the LaTeX

For now the only workaround is write $7ms$, but that isn't really the effect I wanted.  And I have no idea why writing $7$ms doesn't work either.

Comment: `- $<$ 7ms` should work but you need a space between $ and 7. Do you require there's no displayed space between < and 7?

Comment: I thought I didn't want the space, but it actually looks OK, so thanks!